# Shopify wishlist app - displaying item information from products.json?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, shopify

I'm trying to finish the front-end of my shopify wishlist app.

-My app uses a database with each record contains a product ID that the client has wishlisted.

The logic:
-I have a front-end shopify page with a div tag containing the client's ID. (if signed in)
-I use javascript to grab the client's ID and then grab all the product IDs from my app's database.
[Up to this point it works fine, I have the product IDs]
-Now I'm calling `axios.post(appDomain + '/api/showWishlist', {shop_id: Shopify.shop,customer_id: customer})`
-Inside my api.php file I have: `Route::post('showWishlist', 'App\Http\Controllers\WishlistController@show');` 
-Which then my show function in my wishlistController file has php code that needs to return the product info (name, price, image, etc.) from the store's products.json.

This is where my problem lies. I can't seem to be able to grab the product info based on the ID. My original idea was to use graphQL in my controller function, but I believe that it only works for the website's owner as Auth::user() is required to run the graphQL?

How can I get the shopify product details (name,price,etc.) by using the product's ID from my wishlistController.php file?

Comment: But is the scopes are for the, is all the needy ones are there?

Comment: If you want to get the product information, you write the code and use Shopify product AJAX API that not need any API access, but it only works on the Shop frontend. so if you want to use it, you need to develop logic according to your needs. [Link](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/product)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already running an App, your best bet is re-factor it to be embedded (or just installed) in the shop itself, with permission to read products. In the front end, you use the App Proxy to call your App with product ID and customer IDs. You can then call Shopify, get the correct product information based on the IDs, and provide a nice JSON payload back to the front-end, all securely. This is the preferred pattern and without it, you're in for a tough slog. You could try tap-dancing with StorefrontAPI permissions, but still. You also expose your own App to abuse since you make no mention of you are securing your data. With the Shopify embedded App approach, you are protected.

Comment: We do note that since App Proxy is not actually ensuring the customer ID sent in the payload belongs to the logged in customer, you'll have to deal with that scenario as you see fit.